# Basic questions on the homotopy category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

I apologize in advance if this the answer to this question is standard or well-known. I am not in any way an algebraic topologist.

$\newcommand{\s}{\mathscr}$Let $\s T$ be the category of topological spaces, $\s T_*$ the category of pointed topological spaces. We can construct the homotopy category $\s H$ and the "pointed homotopy category" $\s H_{*}$ by letting $\hom_{\s H}(X,Y)$ be $\hom_{\s T}(X,Y)$ modulo homotopy and $\hom_{\s H_*}(X,Y)$ be $\hom_{\s T_*}(X,Y)$ modulo homotopies preserving basepoints. There are obvious functors $F:\s T\to \s H$, $F_{*}:\s T_{*}\to \s H_{*}$.

My questions are pretty basic: do $F,F_*$ preserve products? arbitrary limits? only arbitrary finite limits? coproducts? arbitrary colimits? It not, how does one compute colimits in $\s H$ and $\s H_{*}$?

If this can be found in a standard reference, just write an answer saying "this is a stupid question - this is all worked out in...," and I'll upvote and accept.

Comment: Products and coproducts, yes. Most other limits and colimits, no. I recommend it as exercise to see why and why not. A bit more subtle: many diagrams in the homotopy categories do not even have limits or colimits. I don't have a reference.

Comment: From my spectator's vantage point, the most intriguing property of the homotopy category is its nonconcretizability. This is a theorem of Freyd, discussed in tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/6/tr6abs.html. He begins with a criterion involving kernels (normal subobjects), but immediately remarks (page 3): "There are very few kernels, indeed there are very few monomorphisms in H." This remark is where my own wild-goose chase began. The remainder of the article develops a more nuanced criterion involving sufficiently prevalent "generalized normal subobjects".

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10364/categorical-homotopy-colimits

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For products and coproducts, this is covered on [page 67-68](http://books.google.com/books?id=5nSCRSN51aoC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=%2522homotopy+category%2522+%2522coproduct%2522&source=bl&ots=nYG-7fQ8L-&sig=96P788qaRX9odI5hoXt4GjltWI4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f0wMUdvxF8jO0QGDo4GgAw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%2522homotopy%2520category%2522%2520%2522coproduct%2522&f=false) of "Introduction to Homotopy Theory" by Martin Arkowitz

To see that the homotopy category is not complete or cocomplete (i.e. that there are diagrams which don't have limits or colimits), check out "[Modern Classical Homotopy Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=ruhFJoMIIPoC&pg=PA435&lpg=PA435&dq=%2522homotopy+category+is+not+complete%2522&source=bl&ots=unbnzxnQEw&sig=bdqSemTchBfKZvCxvpvuy-KxzqQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mE0MUZGGOZKs0AH2-4DwBg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%2522homotopy%2520category%2520is%2520not%2520complete%2522&f=false)" by Jeffrey Strom, page 435. He explicitly constructs a diagram with no colimit.

This question of yours is a good question, because thinking this way (i.e. asking for good categorical properties) has led to lots of theory over the years. I discuss two such cases below, although for your application they will probably not be helpful.

---

I study **model categories**, which are categories where one can "do homotopy theory." So $Top$ and $Top_\ast$ are examples. Let $M$ be a model category (feel free to think of $M$ as $Top$) and let $Ho(M)$ be its homotopy category. It turns out that you get arbitrary products and coproducts in $Ho(M)$ for any model category $M$ (see Hovey's book "Model Categories" 1.3.11). Furthermore, you can sometimes compute products on the model category level, as we'll now discuss.

If one wants $F:M\to Ho(M)$ to preserve products, then one wants $M$ to be a monoidal model category, i.e. to have the structure of a monoidal category (for $Top$ this means having a notion of product, which it does) and to satisfy a coherence condition which says that the monoidal products plays nicely with the model structure. It's proven in Mark Hovey's book *Model Categories* that $Top$ and $Top_\ast$ are monoidal model categories, i.e. have that coherence condition. So $Ho(Top)$ is a monoidal category whose unit is the image under $F$ of the unit in $Top$. In $Top$ the unit is $\ast$ and so it must be $\ast$ again in $Ho(Top)$. Furthermore, this means you can compute products on the model category level, so if someone gives you two objects of $Ho(Top)$ you can find an object $X\in Top$ such that $F(X)$ is the product of in $Ho(Top)$. The same story works with $Top_\ast$, but now the product is the smash product of spaces.

The lack of colimits and limits is remedied in this context by considering homotopy limits and homotopy colimits. The idea here is that if you have a diagram in $Ho(M)$ then that's like a diagram in $M$ where we don't care about replacing objects up to weak equivalence. Given that choice not to care, the homotopy (co)limit is the object completing the diagram, i.e. satisfies a universal property which factors in the ability to replace objects in the diagram by weakly equivalent ones. Here is a good [blog post](http://www.konradvoelkel.com/2012/11/homotopy-limits/) on the subject.

---

The desire for nice categorical properties was one of the reasons people started to study the **stable homotopy category**. A great reference here is Margolis's book "Spectra and the Steenrod Algebra". In the introduction he defines the stable homotopy category in several steps and discusses which limits and colimits you are getting at each step. He mentions that even the category of CW complexes does not have good limit structures, and proceeds to move from CW to the Spanier-Whitehead category (which has stable homotopy classes of maps), and then go one farther to $\mathcal{S}$ (the coproduct completion of the subcategory $SW_f$ of finite complexes, a triangulated category). He discusses in chapter 3 that $\mathcal{S}$ has arbitrary coproducts and arbitrary weak colimits. In chapter 5, section 2, he mentions that it has arbitrary products and discusses weak limits.

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly the sort of perspective I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

The inclusion $\mathbb RP^2\to \mathbb CP^2$ has no kernel in the pointed homotopy category.

Proof:

Suppose $X\to \mathbb RP^2$ is such a kernel. Then maps $S^1\to X$ (in that category) correspond bijectively to maps $S^1\to\mathbb RP^2$ such that the composed map $S^1\to \mathbb CP^2$ is trivial. This means that $\pi_1(X)$ has order $2$.

It follows that there is a map $\mathbb RP^2\to X$ inducing an isomorphism of $\pi_1$. The composed map $\mathbb RP^2\to X\to \mathbb RP^2$ also induces an isomorphism of $\pi_1$, therefore also of $H^1$ with $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients, therefore (using naturality of cup products) an iso of $H^2$ with $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients.

But the map $X\to \mathbb RP^2$ must be zero on $H^2$ because the inclusion $\mathbb RP^2\to\mathbb CP^2$ is an isomorphism on $H^2$ and the composed map $X\to \mathbb RP^2 \to \mathbb CP^2$ is zero.

EDIT:  Also, the degree two map $S^1\to S^1$ has no cokernel. Briefly, any such cokernel would have to be a retract (up to homotopy) of $\mathbb RP^2$, but that would make it either a point or $\mathbb RP^2$ and neither of these does the job.

Comment: Touch\'{e}:):)!

Answer (score 4):

A very concrete example of a cospan having no pullback in the homotopy category, which does not require any knowledge of cohomology or Moore spaces, can be found [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ho%28Cat%29#OtherLimits).  It's phrased in terms of the homotopy category of groupoids, but can easily be translated to speak about $K(\pi,1)$s in the homotopy category of spaces instead.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe the example given in that link shows that a homotopy limit is not always a limit in the homotopy category, but it does not seem to show that there is no limit in the homotopy category. It looks like the limit exists and is a one-point space. 

Comment: Or rather no: in this case, if I understand right, the homotopy limit is also contractible.

Comment: I couldn't really tell how to carry out the presumably trivial translation into the homotopy category  of spaces. Can you say what those spaces come out to  be?

Comment: Just like to add the comments that: (a)  the passage to a homotopy category of course forgets  a lot of structure, and we often need information on the homotopies for calculations, as for example in Homological Perturbation Theory; (b) _colimits_ do occur usefully in Seifert-van Kampen Theorems of various kinds, but they are all of the form that a certain functor, say $\Pi$, from (topological data) $\to$ (algebraic data) preserves _certain_ colimits, and such algebraic dat (except the fundamental group)  have structure in a range of dimensions, to capture   a range of homotopical information. 

Comment: @Tom: The shape of the argument is "Suppose there were a limit in the homotopy category.  Then ... and so we have a contradiction."  In the course of deriving the contradiction, we consider also the homotopy limit of the same diagram, but I don't see how that changes the result we're proving.  Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Adam: replace each group $G$ with its classifying space $B G$.

Comment: To me the shape of the argument seems perfectly sound argument, although it is given in the context of the homotopy category of categories rather than spaces. If you replace each occurrence of "monoid" with "group" and each group G with BG, then you get an argument for TOP too. The argument goes roughly (1) suppose that there exists a certain pullback Q in the homotopy category (2) The same diagram admits a specific homotopy pull-back P (by a specific calc) (3) Thus there must be a map P --> Q (4) There can be no such map (by another specific calc), hence no such Q. Is there an error in 2? 4? 

Answer (score 3):

As Tom points out, many diagrams in the homotopy categories do not even have limits or colimits,  so the forgetful functor cannot  preserve them!

Meanwhile, I too had difficulty chasing this down, until I found the following remark (M. Mather, Pullbacks in homotopy theory, Can. J. Math. 1976):

"For example,  no  essential map  between Eilenberg-MacLane spaces  of different dimensions  has a kernel".

My attempt  at reconstruction goes  as  follows. Let $m,n$  be positive integers and let  $G,H$ be  abelian groups. If $m\neq n$  then any morphism  $K(G,m)\rightarrow K(H,n)$ induces the zero morphism $\pi_\ell(K(G,m))\rightarrow\pi_\ell(K(H,n))$ for each $\ell\geq 0$. However, since the  set of morphisms $K(G,m)\rightarrow K(H,n)$ is in canonical  bijection  with $H^n(K(G,m),H)$ which is typically  nontrivial, such essential morphisms do exist. To see that such a morphism  $K(G,m)\rightarrow K(H,n)$ admits  no kernel, note that if $X\rightarrow K(G,m)$ were  such a kernel then all the induced maps  $\pi_\ell(X)\rightarrow\pi_\ell(K(G,m))$ would be  bijections (for $\ell=m$  because $\pi_m(K(H,n))=0$, for  $\ell\neq m$ because $\pi_\ell(K(G,m))=0$) so  that $X\rightarrow K(G,m)$  would be an  isomorphism   in the homotopy category, whence $K(G,m)\rightarrow K(H,n)$ must be inessential.

I have been meaning  to post  my own question regarding whether  anyone happens to  know a simpler example (or a  recipe, or a reference) of a diagram which fails to  have co/limits.

Comment: Yes, I do happen to know of a simpler example and posted it right on this thread moments after you posted this answer. It's in the book by Jeffrey Strom, and I linked to a google books preview of the relevant pages

Comment: Thanks, David. Still, is that (failure of) coimit example so much easier than the limit example with Eilenberg-MacLane spaces?  I'm no  algebraic topologist  either,  so I wouldn't know one way or the other. Maybe it's  the verification that's easier? I'm not particularly comfortable with any  of these spaces - I think I'd feel better about an example, say a map with no kernel, arising in the context of compact manifolds,  finite simplicial complexes, etc. Can this be arranged?

Comment: Well, the first example of an essential map between E-M spaces of different "dimensions" is the inclusion $\mathbb RP^\infty\to \mathbb CP^\infty$. This has no kernel. I guess neither does the inclusion $\mathbb RP^2\to \mathbb CP^2$.


Comment: True, true. I don't think you got that far when you taught ne in Math 272.

Comment: I'm not sure I knew this when I taught you in Math 272. 


Comment: Well, a lot can happen in 29 years.

Comment: To explain Mather's quoted comment: If a map $A\to B$ has a kernel $K$ then $\pi_jK\cong ker(\pi_jA\to \pi_jB)$. When $A=K(G,m)$ and $\pi_mB=0$ then this implies $K\sim A$; $A$ is the kernel. But that means that every map $X\to A$ gives trivial $X\to B$, for every $X$. And that means $A\to B$ is trivial.